# How long after the tax year can you file form 8606

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, irs

During many years in the 1990s I did not show a deductible IRA contribution on my 1040, but deposited money into my IRA account without filling our form 8606.

Answer (score 3):

If for any tax year, you were *eligible* to make *deductible* contributions to a Traditional IRA, and *did* make the contributions in timely fashion, then there is no need to file Form 8606 for that year. Form 8606 (which
tracks your basis in the IRA) is needed if

- you *made* 
  the contribution to your Traditional IRA but **forgot** to *deduct* the contribution from your income on Form 1040 (and thus received no tax benefit for it), and now want to treat it as a nondeductible contribution.  In addition to the tax returns for those years mentioned
  by JoeTaxpayer, you will
  likely need copies of Forms 5498 "IRA Contribution Information" sent to
  you by your IRA custodian showing that you actually *made* the contributions. Copies of Annual Statements might do too if they
  mention the year of contribution etc.

Form 8606 is also needed if

- you were *ineligible* to make *deductible* contributions to your
  Traditional IRA, but made *nondeductible* contributions instead. These
  monies will not be taxed when you start taking *distributions* from your
  IRA, and Form 8606 will be used again to determine how much of your
  distribution is nontaxable income. Once again, Forms 5498 and/or Annual
  Statements will likely be necessary.

Comment: Isn't the 8606 purpose to track basis, the non deducted IRA deposits?

Comment: Yes, the 8606 tracks the basis (the nondeductible or nondeducted) contributions to Traditional IRAs. I am not sure whether just filing Form 8606 for the first time ever along with the 2016 return and pretending that the basis has been tracked all along is going to work, or if the IRS will look back and try to see whether earlier Forms 8606 were ever filed will work. The IRS's default position is that in the absence of Forms 8606, all money coming out of a Traditional IRA is taxable income.

Answer (score 0):

An amended return is required for situations that impact tax owed, or your tax refund. 8606 purpose is to track non-deducted IRA deposits. I'd recommend you gather all your returns to form a paper trail, and when filing your 2016 return, show a proper 8606 as if you'd tracked it all along.